# How do you do calculations using various variables in a toplevel window?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm creating a calculator app for my company which will be used for the calculation of certain parameters.Since there are various parameters with their respective formulas,I decided to create toplevel windows for each parameter-all linked to respective buttons.  But I can't get the functions to work in the toplevel windows.

I've used `def calculate():` to no avail

I expect it to work, since it works in a normal window, but it fails in a toplevel window.

```py
def open():  
    ldl_window = Toplevel(root)
    ldl_window.geometry('500x500')

def calculate():

    tc = eval(totalChol.get())
    hdl=eval (hdLipo.get())
    tg=eval (trig.get ()) 
    ldl =tc-((hdl/2)+tg)
    output_label.configure(text = 'LDL: {:.1f}'.format(ldl))
    totalChol.delete(0,END)
    hdLipo.delete(0,END)
    trig.delete(0,END)

    output_label = Label(font=('Verdana', 16), bg='grey',fg='white')
    tc_label = Label(ldl_window,text='TC',font=('Verdana', 15))
    tc_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    hdl_label = Label(ldl_window,text='HDL',font=('Verdana', 15))
    hdl_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    tg_label = Label(ldl_window,text='TG',font=('Verdana', 15))
    tg_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

    totalChol = Entry(ldl_window,font=('Verdana', 15), width=4)
    totalChol.grid(row=0, column=1)
    hdLipo= Entry(ldl_window,font=('Verdana', 15), width=4)
    hdLipo.grid(row=1,column=1)
    trig= Entry(ldl_window,font=('Verdana', 15), width=4)
    trig.grid (row=2,column=1)

    calc_button = Button(ldl_window,text='CALC', font= 
    ('CALIBRI',15),command=calculate,bg='blue',fg='white')
    calc_button.grid(row=3, column=0)

    output_label.grid(row=3, column=1)

    btn = Button(root, text = "Calculate LDL", command = open, 
    bg='blue',fg='white',font=('CALIBRI', 12))  
    btn.grid(row=3, column=0)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck.

Comment: You have **indentation errors**, [edit] your question and correct this.